# The CSS transforms that I used don't work in mozilla Firefox

Tags: css, css-transforms, vendor-prefix

My animations arent working in mozilla but they are working in chrome. Please suggest some changes so that it works in

```
a {
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
}

a:hover {
    transform:rotate(360deg) ;
    -moz-transform:rotate(360deg);  
    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: If your question is answered, click the checkmark left of the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
display: inline-block;
```

to your link styles.

It seems like Firefox refuses to transform *inline elements*.

Check demo:

> http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPVVXM